# Are there infinitely many Substrimes in any base?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, number-systems, pattern-recognition

$\bullet \textbf{ Explanation}$

A "substrime" is a prime in which all substrings are prime. The number $373$ is an example since $3,7,37,73,$ and $373$ are each prime numbers. In decimal (base-10) the only substrimes are:
$$2,3,5,7,23,37,53,73,373.$$
See: https://oeis.org/A085823

But we can look at substrimes in any base. For example in base-5 the substrimes are
$$2,3,23,32,232.$$

There are $103$ substrimes in base-24 the largest of which is 
$$266003=(19)(5)(19)(11)|_{24}.$$

We computed these up to base-100 and found base-90 had the most; $1455$ in total (live code: https://repl.it/@onnomc/substrimes).

$\bullet \textbf{ Question}$

Does any base have *infinitely* many substrimes?

$\bullet \textbf{ Attempt}$

Every substrime of $n$ digits can be thought of as two substrimes on $n-1$ digits such that cutting off the leftmost digit of one and the rightmost digit of the other give a substrime of length $n-2$. For example, in base $28$ the substrime 
$$(11)(3)(23)(3)|_{28}=244471$$
 has $4$ digits. It can be viewed as the substrimes
$$(11)(3)(23)|_{28}=8731\quad\text{and}\quad(3)(23)(3)|_{28}=2999$$
which share a common substrime $(3)(23)|_{28}=107$ obtained after truncation.

So let "$S_b(n)$" mean "the amount of substrimes with $n$ digits in base $b$". From the previous bit we obtain two inequalities 
$$(1)\quad S_b(n)\le S_b(1)\cdot S_b(n-1)$$
$$(2)\quad S_b(n)\le S_b(n-1)^2$$
which paired with the prime number theorem gives us heuristics
$$(1)\quad S_b(n) \approx \frac{S_b(1)\cdot S_b(n-1)}{n\log b}=C_b\frac{S_b(n-1)}{n}$$
$$(2)\quad S_b(n)\approx C_b'\frac{S_b(n-1)^2}{n}$$

Thus we would expect $S_b(n)$ to hit zero eventually since the numerator grows at best like O$(n^2)$ but the denominator grows like O$(n!)$.

But of course, this is hueristic. It seems also highly composite bases have more substrimes. For example, the record holder bases with the most susbstrimes are:
$$3,4,5,7,8,12,18,24,30,42,48,54,60,90,...$$

Here is a chart:
[image]

I was unable to determine why composite bases have more substrimes.

Comment: Regarding why composite bases generally have more substrimes, it's to some extent due to what's shown in the proposed duplicate's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3247061/602049). For base $b$, it shows how you will eventually get non-primes modulo $c = b - 1$. You can see the composite bases with more substrimes are generally $1$ more than a larger prime. For example, for $b = 90$, $c = 90 - 1 = 89$ is a prime. Likewise for $b = 84$ as $c = 83$ is a prime. However, with $b = 98$, $c = 97$ is prime, but it doesn't have many substrimes, so this only gives a partial explanation.